# DRY meta-code in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, dry

I have this type of situation in Objective-C:

```
[aCoder encodeObject:self.control forKey:@"control"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.command forKey:@"command"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.channel forKey:@"channel"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.data1 forKey:@"data1"];
```

In Ruby or Groovy I could do this with blocks and a tiny bit of messing around to have one line rather than four. I know Objective-C has many dynamic features. How can this code be distilled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `performSelector:withObject:`

```
for (NSString *key in arrayOfKeys) {
  SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(key);
  id anObject = [self performSelector:aSelector withObject:nil];
  [aCoder encodeObject:anObject forKey:key];
}
```

This is how you dynamically call a method at run time with only the name of that method as a string.  The `withObject:` argument is a single object passed as as the single argument for a method, if it takes one.

If it takes more than one argument, or takes a non-object argument, you have to look into the far more complicated `NSInvocation` and it's buddy `NSMethodSignature`.  Sadly, they are not very simple but they do allow you to achieve some impressive dynamism, if even their use is complicated and ugly.

Comment: awesome, just what I needed, thanks! Does this get tighter/better with blocks?

Comment: The only block that would be used here in a language like ruby, would be to pass in this code to `Array#each`.  But since ObjC supports a for/each style loop natively, we don't really need to do that.  You could, of course, do something with blocks and an iterator, but it wouldn't solve anything and getting the selector and calling it on `self` to get the value of a property wouldn't be changed from this example at all.  Blocks would just needlessly complicated this.  Unless you had a real good reason.

Comment: @Yar, it's not as nice as ruby (by a long shot), but you can use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: to make this cleaner.

Comment: @Adam Milligan: I love using blocks, but using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` would actually be *more* verbose than this. It would replace `for (NSString *key in arrayOfKeys) {}` with `[arrayOfKeys enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {}]`.

Comment: @Chuck: Or possibly `[arrayOfKeys enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:encodeNamedProperty];`  But, I take your point.

Comment: Why so complicated and not just for(...) {[aCode encodeObject:[self valueForKey:key] forKey:key]}?

Comment: @w. m: that's a great point. Since `valueForKey` and `setValue:forKey` (since I have a decode method too) exist, there's no reason to use the selector. If you put that as an answer I'd have to choice but to mark it best answer, but @Squeegy's answer is also important to have on hand. Thanks!

Comment: Once you include `NSArray *arrayOfKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"control", @"command", @"channel", nil];` the answer becomes so verbose that you'd have to have many keys before you even considered it.

Comment: On second thought, this is not really that verbose because you only need this code ONCE in an NSObject category. I still use this, thanks.